# 835 format - is CAS segments can contain multiple loops?

Tags: format, edi, x12

I'm taking care a 835 format which is and `EDI` response.

I have this response which got 2 `CLP` and several `CAS` segments:

```
ISA*00*..........*01*SECRET....*ZZ*123456         *ZZ*AAAAAA         *030101*1253*^*00501*000000905*1*T*:~
GS*HP*SENDER CODE*RECEIVER CODE*19991231*0802*1*X*005010X221A1~  
ST*835*112233~       
BPR*I*945*C*ACH*CCP*01*888999777*DA*24681012*1935665544**01*111333555*DA*144444*20020316~        
TRN*1*71700666555*1935665544~        
DTM*405*20020314~        
N1*PR*BLABLABLA BLA~             
N3*10 SOUTH AVENUE~          
N4*RAPID CITY*SD*57701~          
PER*BL~
N1*PE*ACME MEDICAL CENTER*XX*1232343560~             
REF*TJ*777667755~            
LX*1~            
CLP*5554555444*1*800*450*300*12*94060555410000~              
CAS*CO*45*50~       
CAS*OA*44*48~
CAS*OA*44*1~
CAS*PI*43*838~
CAS*PI*44*1~
CAS*PR*486*234.1~
CAS*PR*486*1.8~
NM1*QC*1*BUDD*DUDUDU****MI*33344555510~              
REF*CE*12345~                
AMT*AU*700~              
SVC*HC:99211*800*500~                    
DTM*150*20020301~                    
DTM*151*20020304~                    
CAS*PR*1*301~                    
AMT*B6*750~                  
CLP*8765432112*1*1200*495*600*12*9407779923000~              
CAS*CO*45*55~                
NM1*QC*1*SETTLE*SUSAN****MI*44455666610~                 
REF*CE*12447~                
AMT*AU*900~              
SVC*HC:93555*1200*550~                   
DTM*150*20020310~                    
DTM*151*20020312~                    
CAS*PR*1*600~                    
CAS*CO*210*50~                   
AMT*B6*1100~                     
SE*39*112233~        
GE*1*1~  
IEA*1*000000905~
```

I need to take care for `CAS` segments which located in loop `2110-Service Payment Information`.

My question is, is there a possibility to have multiple CAS segments as a multiple levels inside 2110 loop?

I'm asking it in order to know if I need to create a recursive function to process this data.

Answer (score 0):

As is, the above looks incorrect. You can only have one code per Claim Adjustment Group Code CAS 01 and CAS 02 per 2110 loop. What you CAN do is request a different Adjustment Reason Code (CAS 02) per code OR require multiple 2100 loops. Personally, I would go with the multiple 2100 loops but both should work depending on your system.

Why are they (or you) sending multiple CAS segments with the same codes in the first place?

Comment: About your question, the tested file that i'm working on is just for testing. What you actually saying is that we need to have MAXIMUM one CAS segment per each code?

Comment: I suppose I should clarify. The file should only have a MAXIMUM of one CAS segment with CAS 01 + CAS 02 unique combo per loop. So: `CAS*CO`       
`CAS*OA` is fine but `CAS*CO` `CAS*CO` is not. Do you happen to have a spec with this Vendor or are you the vendor? If its an existing spec, you may be able to get clarification from the vendor themselves.

Comment: Ok, that what I was asking, thank you for your reply. From where do you have this info? documentation?

Comment: Yes. Most of the time, the vendor will give you a spec. If you are the vendor, then you can get the official spec from http://store.x12.org/store/tr3-spreadsheets